# When to use attr:accessors in place of a permanent column in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm creating my own website using Ruby on Rails. One thing that I've failed to comprehend is why and when to use `attr:accessors` in place of a permanent column for a model. For instance, let's say that I created a 'posts' model which would have a title, description and some content associated with it. Now should I do `rails g model Post title:string description:text content:text` or should I declare them as `attr:accessible :title, :description, :content`.

I'm not very experienced in rails, so please bear with me if this sounds too silly to you.

Comment: `attr_accessor` is not the same as `attr_accessible`. Totally different things!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev please explain the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `attr_accessor` if you need virtual attributes in model.

**For eg:** In contact us form you need not to see form data, but you need to send that data using email. So you can create `attr_accessor` for adding virtual attributes and can also apply validations on that.

```
class Contact
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :content

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i
  validates_length_of :content, :maximum => 500

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

[ref](http://railscasts.com/episodes/326-activeattr?view=asciicast)

`attr_accessible` is to white list of attributes that can be mass assigned in model.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :content
end

def create
  #so here params[:comment], have all parameters. But if those params are not in attr_accessible list it will not save it. 
  # you can try that by remove attr_accessible from model

  @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
  if @comment.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created comment."
    redirect_to @comment
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment Form:

```
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

Happy Coding...

Comment: @PradeepDhingra That's a really nice explanation, but suppose I have a model for modelling comments. It only needs two columns, a user and the content. Now, what would you propose I use? virtual attributes or permanent tables

Comment: @AnkitKulshrestha   you must need permanent attributes in that case as you have to save that data. `attr_accessor` we generally use for the fields which we don't want to save permanenty.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra Ah,that's the important point! Thanks for the info

Comment: @AnkitKulshrestha if that answers your question please mark it correct.. Thanks

Comment: Accept `Pardeep`'s answer, it's legendary

Answer (score 0):

To add to `Pardeep`'s epic answer, you'll want to look at [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes) (RE "virtual attributes"):

[image]

[`attr_accessor`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html) basically creates a [`setter` & `getter`](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/45-more-classes/lessons/110-instance-variables#317) method in the model.

Probably doesn't make any sense; what you have to remember is that each `Rails` model is a *class*. Classes form the backbone of [object-orientated programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

Since Ruby is object orientated, each time you do anything with the language, it expects classes to be invoked & manipulated. The basis of OOP is to load classes into memory & play with them; [good write-up here](http://superprofundo.com/2010/12/09/object-oriented-programming-in-a-nutshell/).

In classic OOP, your classes would be hard-coded with a series of attributes:

```
class Mario
   def jump
     pos_y + 5
   end

   def pos_y
      # gets y val from the viewport
   end
end
```

This will allow you to send instructions to the program, in turn modifying the class:

```
@mario.jump
```

... this should modify the viewport etc in the way you defined within the class.

--

Rails is very similar to the above, except most of the attributes are defined by ActiveRecord;

```
#app/models/mario.rb
class Mario < ActiveRecord::Base
   # attributes from db include height, weight, color etc
end
```

Rails models allow you to call:

```
@mario = Mario.find x
@mario.height = "255"
```

... however, they don't allow you to create attributes which are stored in memory only.

For example...

```
#app/models/mario.rb
class Mario < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :grown
end
```

The above will give you an instance value of `grown`, which will allow you to populate this independently of the database.

So say you wanted to...

```
@mario = Mario.find x
@mario.grown = true if params[:grown]
@mario.height += "150" if @mario.grown
```

---

Regarding the difference between `attr_accessor` and `attr_accessible`, you'll want to look up Rails 3 and mass assignment.

I came into Rails ~ 4.0, so I didn't have to deal with `attr_accessible` so much; it was basically the way to permit parameters in Rails 3 models.

In Rails 4/5, you use [`strong params`](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) in the controller:

```
#app/controllers/mario_controller.rb
class MarioController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @mario = Mario.new mario_params
      @mario.save
   end

   private

   def mario_params
      params.require(:mario).permit(:x, :y, :z)
   end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, my basic confusion was that why and when I gotta use database persistent columns and when to use otherwise. Thanks for taking the time to write such a detailed answer.